# How to calculate the average number of unique text in excel?

Tags: excel, average

Hello everyone im doing this excel spreadsheet and there is one particular question that im stuck on.

Im trying to find the number of unique names in a column

So far i have done

```
=AVERAGE(SUM(1/COUNTIF(C2:D57142,C2:D57142)))
```

and press shift + ctrl + enter but it gives 0.

Comment: Can it be done with an overly complicated, calculation intensive formula? Probably, but I'm not even going to bother attempting a formula since a VBA User Defined Function is the best way to do this. Using a Scripting.Dictionary of Scripting.Dictionaries or variant arrays as .Items is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

That would probably be dividing number of unique values of strategy names to number of unique values of campaign names. Note that SUMPRODUCT is similar to Array of Formula only there is no need to press Ctrl + Shift + Enter in order to place your formula into { }.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(D2:D57142,D2:D57142&""))/SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C2:C57142,C2:C57142&""))
```

or with Array Formula by pressing Ctrl +Shift + Enter

```
{=SUM(1/COUNTIF(D2:D57142,D2:D57142&""))/SUM(1/COUNTIF(C2:C57142,C2:C57142&""))}
```

**UPDATE: as Jeeped noted *"This should work if the strategy names are unique to each campaign name"***

Comment: This should work if the strategy names are unique to each campaign name but would seem to return bad results if one or more strategy names were associated to more than a single campaign name. Nice formula though.

Comment: Ray Bashir, maybe calculations are set to manual (though once you edit the cell it should calculate), hit F9 to calculate the sheet. It does calculate on my test data, however as Jeeped noted it would show bad data if strategy names repeat for other campaign names.